# is state guaranteed in render after setState called in componentWillMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I call `setState` in `componentWillMount` is the state guaranteed to exist in the `render` method? Note I am NOT calling setState in a callback.

Facebook states: "componentWillMount is called before render(), therefore calling setState() synchronously in this method will not trigger an extra rendering."

The quote "Not triggering an extra render" sort of implies to me that `this.state` will be what was set in `componentWillMount`, but I'm not entirely clear if that is the case. Can someone shed more light? (Since  `setState` is an async operation, I'm not sure if I'm introducing race conditions or if the render lifecycle method is guaranteed after the `setState` in a `componentWillMount`)

For example:

```
class Blah extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({ someState })
    }
    render() {
        // this.state.someState <--- guaranteed to be the value I set in componentWillMount?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will with no extra rendering as stated in the React documentation:

*componentWillMount() is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It is called before render(), therefore calling setState() synchronously in this method will not trigger an extra rendering.*

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount